# Dual semi-definite programming formulation of the quantum adversary method

Tags: semidefinite-programming

I'm reading about the quantum adversary method and its semi-definite program formulation. It is not clear to me how to arrive to the dual SDP problem as usually found (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09415.pdf) page 101). Given a boolean function $f : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, the quantum adversary lower bound SDP is

\begin{align}
\max_\Gamma\ \ & ||\Gamma|| \\
  s.t.\ \ & ||\Gamma_i|| \le 1 \\
  \ \ & \Gamma_{xy} = 0 \ \ \ \forall x, y : f(x) = f(y)
\end{align}

where $\Gamma_i$ is constructed from $\Gamma$ by zeroing out $\Gamma_{xy}$ if $x_i = y_i$ i.e., the two inputs $x,y$ agree on the $i$-th bit. I can rewrite it as

\begin{align}
\max\ \ & \varepsilon \\
  s.t.\ \ & {-}\varepsilon I \preceq \Gamma \preceq \varepsilon I \\
  \ \ & {-}I \preceq \Gamma_i \preceq I \\
  \ \ & \Gamma_{xy} = 0 \ \ \ \forall x, y : f(x) = f(y) \\
  \ \ & \varepsilon \ge 0
\end{align}

And I'm stuck here. What are the next steps?